# catch file I/O errors

Tags: php, error-handling, io

If I try to write to a file handle,

```
$ php5 -a
Interactive mode enabled

php > $f = fopen('/dev/full','w+b');
php > var_dump(fwrite($f, 'lolcat'));
int(0)
php >
```

`fwrite()` returns 0, but doesn't tell for which reason the write failed.

If I try to read from a file handle,

```
$ php5 -a
Interactive mode enabled

php > $f = fopen('/proc/self/mem', 'rb');
php > var_dump(strlen(fread($f, 1000)));
int(0)
php > var_dump(feof($f));
bool(true)
php >
```

I can't even tell I/O errors from EOF.

How can I fix this while supporting PHP 5.3 on every platform (at least *nix and WinNT) and still working with file handles as returned from `fopen()`?

Comment: What's `var_dump($f)`? Have you enabled `display_errors`? ( `php -d` )

Comment: In both cases: `resource(2) of type (stream)` and `-d display_errors=1` doesn't change anything.